# Efficient evaluation of real/imaginary parts of long expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have the following, rather compact, but complex, expression (see below). I simply want the real part of this. Now, when I do the usual, i.e., `ComplexExpand[Re[...]]//Simplify` , since all parameters and functions are real, the number of terms produced by `ComplexExpand` is, apparently, too large (about 6000 terms) for `Simplify` to handle. It has been running for almost an hour now, without any sign of it concluding with an answer.

From similar expressions in the same context I know that the result of the simplification is rather compact as well (just like the expression I start with), so I am wondering whether there is a way to skip the "Expand" part of `ComplexExpand`? Why expand into thousands of terms, when it then all re-collapses into a compact expression?

There got to be a more efficient way, no?

```
-((I E^(I m ϕ + t ωi - 
  I t ωr) ((1/(
   1 + (iν - 
       I rν)^2 χ^2 Cos[θ]^2))(r^2 + χ^2 Cos[\
 θ]^2) (-1 + (2 r)/(
      r^2 + χ^2 Cos[θ]^2)) (-m χ (r (-2 + 
            r (I iν + 
               rν)^2 ((-2 + r) r + χ^2)) + (I iν + 
            rν)^2 χ^2 (r^2 + χ^2) Cos[θ]^2) \
   (I RaI[r] + RaR[r]) (I SaI[θ] + 
         SaR[θ]) + (I ωi + ωr) (-r (r^3 + (2 \
    + r + r^3 (iν - I rν)^2 + 
               2 r^2 (I iν + rν)^2) χ^2 + 
            r (iν - I rν)^2 χ^4) + χ^2 (r (2 - 
               r + 2 r^2 (I iν + rν)^2) + (-1 + 
               r^2 (I iν + rν)^2) χ^2 + (I iν + 
               rν)^2 χ^4) Cos[θ]^2) (I RaI[r] + 
         RaR[r]) (I SaI[θ] + SaR[θ]) + 
      r (I iν + 
         rν) ((-2 + 
            r) r + χ^2) (r^2 + χ^2) (-1 + (I iν + 
            rν)^2 χ^2 Cos[θ]^2) (I SaI[θ] +
          SaR[θ]) (I Derivative[1][RaI][r] + 
         Derivative[1][RaR][r]) - (I iν + rν) (1 + 
         r^2 (I iν + rν)^2) χ^2 ((-2 + 
            r) r + χ^2) Cos[θ] (I RaI[r] + 
         RaR[r]) Sin[θ] (I Derivative[1][SaI][θ] + 
         Derivative[1][SaR][θ])) + (
   1/(-1 + (I iν + rν)^2 χ^2 Cos[θ]^2))
   2 r χ Sin[θ]^2 (1/
       2 r (I iν + 
         rν) χ ((-2 + r) r + χ^2) (-2 + (I iν + 
            rν)^2 χ^2 + (I iν + 
            rν)^2 χ^2 Cos[2 θ]) (I SaI[θ] +
          SaR[θ]) (I Derivative[1][RaI][r] + 
         Derivative[1][RaR][r]) - (I RaI[r] + 
         RaR[r]) ((-r χ (-2 + 
               r (I iν + 
                rν)^2 ((-2 + 
                r) r + χ^2)) (I ωi + ωr) + 
            m χ^2 (1 + (I iν + 
                rν)^2 χ^2) Cot[θ]^2 - (I iν + 
               rν)^2 χ^3 Cos[θ]^2 ((r^2 + \
   χ^2) (I ωi + ωr) + m χ Cot[θ]^2) + 
            m r (-2 + r + 2 r^2 (iν - I rν)^2 + 
               r^3 (I iν + rν)^2 + 
               r (I iν + 
                rν)^2 χ^2) Csc[θ]^2) (I SaI[\
    θ] + SaR[θ]) + (I iν + rν) (1 + 
            r^2 (I iν + rν)^2) χ ((-2 + 
               r) r + χ^2) Cot[θ] (I Derivative[1][
              SaI][θ] + 
            Derivative[1][SaR][θ])))))/((1 + 
   r^2 (I iν + rν)^2) ((-2 + 
      r) r + χ^2) (r^2 + χ^2 Cos[θ]^2)^2))
```